# Minimum hardware and software requirements to develop apps on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8

Windows 8 was previewed yest at BUILD.

What are the minimum hardware and software requirements to develop XAML-based apps on Windows 8?

Comment: This isn't a real question anywhere (no, not even on superuser). It can't be answered because Windows 8 is still only at preview stage and the min requirements are not determined yet.

Comment: David, so asking questions about pre-release software is forbidden? That's news to me.

Comment: I am asking it so I can be better informed and better prepared before the final release. For once, I want to be an early adopter.

Comment: @David, I see nothing wrong with this question, as it already had a good answer.   Yes the answer may change over time, but it is still a valid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the webpage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516

> System Requirements
>
> Windows Developer Preview works great on the same hardware that powers
>   Windows Vista and Windows 7:
>
> - 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor
> - 1 gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
> - 16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
> - DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver
> - Taking advantage of touch input requires a screen that supports
>     multi-touch